# Xamarin.Forms default control templates

Tags: xamarin.forms, controltemplate

I would like to adjust the default controltemplate of a Button. In WPF i would just use blend to see the default controltemplate but for Xamarin.Forms  i can not use blend.

Also in the App.xaml file i see a reference to

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Resource Dictionaries/StandardStyles.xaml"/>
```

but i do not find the StandardStyles.xaml file so i am out of luck there as well.

And on the Xamarin site i do not find the default controltemplates neither.
So where/how can i find the default controltemplates for the Xamarin.Forms controls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point, `Xamarin.Forms` doesn't provide templating support for buttons - so there is no default template(s) to refer (as we do in WPF) or `ControlTemplate` property in `Button`. It simply renders the platform version of button in target platform.

Control templates usually are supported by controls that have a `Content` property. A good example would be [`ContentView`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.TemplatedView.ControlTemplate/). You can write a custom button control while extending a `ContentView`, while providing templating support, and use `ContentPresenter` to render the associated button.

### EDIT 1 - Custom button control with templated support

**For example:**

```
public class TemplatedButton : ContentView
{
    public TemplatedButton()
    {
        var button = new Button();
        button.SetBinding(Button.TextColorProperty, new Binding(nameof(TextColor), source: this));
        button.SetBinding(BackgroundColorProperty, new Binding(nameof(BackgroundColor), source: this));

        button.SetBinding(IsEnabledProperty, new Binding(nameof(IsEnabled), source: this));
        button.SetBinding(Button.TextProperty, new Binding(nameof(Text), source: this));

        button.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(Command), source: this));
        button.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding(nameof(CommandParameter), source: this));

        var tapGestureRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();
        tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandProperty, new Binding(nameof(Command), source: this));
        tapGestureRecognizer.SetBinding(TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameterProperty, new Binding(nameof(CommandParameter), source: this));
        GestureRecognizers.Add(tapGestureRecognizer);

        Content = button;
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(TemplatedButton),
            defaultValue: default(string));

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "Command", typeof(ICommand), typeof(TemplatedButton),
            defaultValue: new Command((obj) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("TemplatedButton Tapped")));

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CommandParameterProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "CommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(TemplatedButton),
            defaultValue: default(object));

    public object CommandParameter
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty TextColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(
            "TextColor", typeof(Color), typeof(TemplatedButton),
            defaultValue: default(Color));

    public Color TextColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(TextColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
<!-- App/Page resources -->
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ThreeBorderBtn">
        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0">
            <BoxView Margin="5" BackgroundColor="Purple" />
            <BoxView Margin="10" BackgroundColor="Green" />
            <BoxView Margin="15" BackgroundColor="Red" />
            <ContentPresenter Margin="20" />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- Control usage -->
<!-- make sure to register xmlns:local namespace --> 
<local:TemplatedButton 
    HeightRequest="100"
    Text="Button Caption!" 
    TextColor="Teal" 
    Command="{Binding ClickCommand}"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    ControlTemplate="{StaticResource ThreeBorderBtn}" />
```